# Table with max width doesnt contain cell data of width 100%

Tags: html, css, width

In the following [JS-Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/3ona2vvq/#&togetherjs=xdmj7sUfzg), why the inner table expand to the width of the screen, when its container has a max width property set?

```
<table bgcolor="white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="max-width:580px; border: solid 1px green">
      <table bgcolor="red" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            MY TEST CELL!!
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The code in your question doesn't match the fiddle. Add a [mcve] to your question please.

Comment: `display: block;` on the `td` will fix it but i don't know that's what you're after...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<table>` element uses css property `display: table` which doesn't behave "normally". If you want your elements to behave as expected, use `display: inline-block` or `display: block`. This way your element will actually pay attention to your `max-width` declaration.

However, it seems you are trying to use tables to layout your content, and this is a bad practice. Tables are used for tabular data only. If your content is a paragraph, use `<p>`, for instance.

Also try to avoid inline styling, always use external css files.